# Does MultiPath TCP allow connections to stay open when switching between different Wi-Fi access points?

Tags: android, ios, networking, tcp, websocket

From what I have read MultiPath TCP allows for a TCP socket to stay connected in use cases such as an iPhone switching from Wi-Fi to data/LTE.

For example, if you have an app with a socket connection to a web server (for example an SSH client app) you could be connected while at home on your Wi-Fi, and then walk out of Wi-Fi range; your phone moves to the data connection, and maintains the connection without the application needing to reconnect at all (of course, any good application will still detect a connection loss and attempt to reconnect).

I believe modern iOS and Android both support this use case.

This question: would this also work in practice when moving between different Wi-Fi networks?